# Possible to add URL to jQuery array and do some checks with it

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, loops, each

I'm pretty new to jQuery/JS. But I have loop in jQuery where I would like to do some checks. I would like to check if the URL has already printed or not. The data for the loop comes from JSON if that matters.

Basically I would have a array var = myArray where I would put all the URLs from the loop. I go through that loop with each. Then each time I would check if the URL is already in array. As a pseudo:

```
var myArray = [];
each data {
    myArray.push({'url':data.url});

    if data.url is already in myArray {
        do stuff
    }

    if data.url is not already in myArray {
        do other stuff
    }
}
```

I was playing aounrd with jQuery.inArray() but I always got -1

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your pseudo code you were pushing to the array before you check if it existed, so that it would always be there. That and you need to push `data.url` instead of `{'url':data.url}`

Working example of what you are looking for:

```
var testData = [ 1, 2, 2, 3, 4]
var myArray = []    
jQuery.each( testData, function( pos, val ) {
    // not in array
    if ( jQuery.inArray( val, myArray ) == -1 ) {
        myArray.push( val );

    // in array  
    } else {
        alert( "Already in [" + myArray + "] : " + val );        
    }    
})​;​
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah pushing the info in wrong place was the key here.

Answer (score 1):

Just push the url directly instead of creating an object:

```
myArray.push(data.url);
```

Then `jquery.inarray()` should work just fine

```
if (jquery.inArray(data.url, myArray))
```

However, you will want to add the new url's at the end of the loop instead of at the beginning, or else they will always be in the array when you go to check.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/c2934/

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var myArray = [];
$.each(data, function(i,u) {
   if($.inArray(u, myArray)){
        //DO STUFF IF URL IN ARRAY
   }else{
       myArray.push(u);
       //DO SUTFF IF URL NOT IN ARRAY
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use $.grep()

```
var myArray = [];
var ar = [{'url':'test1'},{'url':'test1'},{'url':'test3'}];
$.each(ar,function(ii,data) {
  if ($.grep(myArray,function(e,i){ return e.url == data.url;   }).length > 0) {
    console.log('in array: ' + data.url);
  } else {
    console.log('not in array: ' + data.url);
  }
  myArray.push({'url': data.url });
});
```